# Game loop not resetting the game after killer is revealed / killed

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, if-statement, getelementbyid

I am trying to create a surivor game vs killer and once the killer is revealed at the end, it will tell who the killer is at the end of the game when there's less than 4 cast members left.

When I try to use an IF statement in the endGame() function to check if the killer name has been assigned after being revealed and the button to press for each new episode is clicked, it will check to see if both are true and then reload the game to replay, unfortunately this isn't working and I'm struggling to find out why.

I did get an error >Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (at game.js:236:7) but I don't understand what this means.

```
let players = 7; // Player count
let episodes = 6; // Episode count
let episodecount = 0; // Episode Value count
let killer; // Initializes killer variable
let killerRevealed = false; // Initializes killerRevealed variable
let stamina; // Stamina stat for each player 
let speed; // Speed stat for each player 
let strength; // Strength stat for each player 
let suspicion; // Suspicion stat for each player 
let highestPlayer; //Highest stat player


let castMembers = [
"Sidney Prescott",
"Gale Weathers",
"Stu Macher",
"Billy Loomis",
"Dewey Riley",
"Tatum Riley",
"Principal Himbry",
"Kenny Brown"
];

let gameStarted = false;
let objects = ["knife", "gun", "shovel", "rope", "candle", "matche", "lighter", "clothesline", "hiding spot", "clue"]; // List of objects 
let events = ["sudden outburst", "false accusation", "heated argument", "suspicious behavior", "mysterious disappearance", "surprising discovery"]; // List of random events
let scenes = ["house party garage scene", "outside van scene", "high school scene", "house party living room", "house party attick"]
let playAs1996Cast = document.getElementById("buttonp")
let killerSet = false;


function getRandom(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

// Function to randomly select the Killer 
function chooseKiller(){
    
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * castMembers.length);
    killer = castMembers[randomNumber];
    console.log ("A new killer has been chosen: " + killer);
    castMembers = castMembers.filter(x => x!== killer);
    document.getElementById("text8").innerHTML = killer;
    console.log (castMembers);
}




// Function to randomly assign Stamina, Speed and Strength stats to each player
function assignStats() {
    // Loop through each player 
    for (let i = 0; i < players; i++) {
        // Assign random values between 0-100 to each stat 
        stamina = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101); 
        speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101); 
        strength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
        suspicion = 0; // Initializes suspicion stat of 0 for each player
        let totalStats = stamina + speed + strength;    // Create a calculation for total combined stats
        
        if (totalStats > highestPlayer) { // Compare total combined stats to the highest score and update if needed
            highestPlayer = totalStats;
        }
    }
    return highestPlayer; // Return the highest score
}

// Function to randomly assign objects to each player 
function assignObjects() {
    let numObjects = Math.floor(Math.random() * (objects.length + 1)); // Choose a random number of objects 
    let assignedObjects = []; // Create an array to store objects
    console.log(numObjects + " objects have been assigned to each player."); 
    for (let i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
        let randomObject = objects[Math.floor(Math.random() * objects.length)]; // Choose a random object from the list  
        assignedObjects.push(randomObject); // Store the object in the array
    }
    return assignedObjects; // Return the array
}

function removeDeadCast() {
    for (let i = 0; i < castMembers.length; i++) {
        if (castMembers[i] == killer & episodecount === 3) {
            castMembers.splice(i, 1); // Removes dead cast member from the game
            console.log("The dead cast member has been removed from the game." + castMembers);
            endGame();
        }
    }
}

// Function to eliminate one player based on all 3 stats
function eliminateOne() {
    
    for (let i = 0; i < players; i++) { // Loop through each player 
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * players); // Choose a random player
    let totalStats = stamina + speed + strength; // Calculate total combined stats
    if (totalStats < 150 && suspicion > 2) { // If the combined stats are less than 150 and suspicion is greater than 2, eliminate the player
        console.log(`Player ${randomNumber} has been eliminated due to low combined stats and high suspicion level! Their name is ${castMembers[randomNumber]}`);
        players--; // Decrement player count 
    }
    }
}

// Function to randomly trigger events 
function triggerEvent() {
    let randomEvent = events[Math.floor(Math.random() * events.length)]; // Choose a random event from the list  
    console.log("The triggerEvent function has been activated. An event occurred: " + randomEvent); // Log the random event 
}

function revealKiller() {
    console.log("The killer has been revealed! It's " + killer + "!");
}

// Function to increase suspicion stat of each Survivor randomly 
function increaseSuspicion() {
    for (let i = 0; i < players; i++) {
        if (i !== killer) { // Increases suspicion only for non-killers
            suspicion++; // Increments suspicion stat by 1
            console.log("The suspicion of player " + i + " has been increased to " + suspicion + ".");
        }
    }
}

function openingScene() {
    
let lowestPlayer = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < castMembers; i++) { // Loop through each player 
    let totalStats = stamina + speed + strength; // Calculate total combined stats
    if (totalStats < lowestPlayer) { // Compare total combined stats to the lowest score and update if needed
        lowestPlayer = totalStats;
        
        break;
    }
}

    let lowestPlayerCastMember = castMembers[lowestPlayer];

    console.log("how many survivors is there in the game (OS)" + castMembers);
    
    document.getElementById("maintext").innerHTML = "Opening Scene";
    document.getElementById("scenebox").style.backgroundImage = "url(./images/s1oc.webp)";  
    document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = "The Phone Rings... and " + lowestPlayerCastMember + " answers the phone";
    
    chooseKiller();
    assignStats();
    assignObjects();
    triggerEvent(); 
    eliminateOne();
    increaseSuspicion();    
    
    console.log("episode count" + episodecount);
    
    episodecount++;
    
    if (lowestPlayer.totalStats=0){
        playEpisode()
    }
}

// Function to play each episode
function playEpisode() {
    
    let lowestPlayer = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < castMembers; i++) { // Loop through each player 
        let totalStats = stamina + speed + strength; // Calculate total combined stats
        if (totalStats < lowestPlayer) { // Compare total combined stats to the lowest score and update if needed
            lowestPlayer = totalStats;  
            break;
        }
    }
            
     if (castMembers < 4) {
        endGame();
    }
    
    let lowestPlayerCastMember = castMembers[lowestPlayer];
    let randomSceneNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * scenes.length);
    
    gameStarted = true;
    
    var img = ["./images/s1oc.webp", "./images/garagekill.gif", "./images/highschoolmurder.gif"]
    
    function imgRandom (imgArr) {
        
        return imgArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArr.length)];
    }
    
    
    document.getElementById("maintext").innerHTML = scenes[randomSceneNumber];
    document.getElementById("scenebox").src = imgRandom(img);
    document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = "The Phone Rings at " + lowestPlayerCastMember + " answers the phone";
    castMembers = castMembers.filter(x => x!== lowestPlayerCastMember);
    console.log("lowestPlayerCastMember");
    console.log(castMembers);
    assignObjects();
    triggerEvent(); 
    eliminateOne();
    increaseSuspicion();    
    episodecount++; // Increment episode count  
    
    console.log("Episode after Opening Scene Count " + episodecount);
}

// Function to detect if the game is in play
function detectGamePlay() {

    // Check if game has started
    if (gameStarted===false) {
        
        if (episodecount ===0) {
            openingScene();
            console.log("Debug 1")
            
        }
        
        else {
            playEpisode();
            console.log("Debug 2")
        }
        
    } else {
            playEpisode();
            console.log("Debug 3")

    }
}

// Function to end game
**function endGame() {
        gameStarted = false; // Set game status to false
        episodecount = 0;
        document.getElementById("objecttext").innerHTML = killer;
        console.log("End Game:" + killer);  

        if (document.getElementById("buttonp").clicked === true & document.getElementById("objecttext").innerHTML = killer){
            location.reload();
        }

}**

console.log("Episode count " + episodecount);

playAs1996Cast.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById("buttonp").innerHTML = "Continue";
    console.log("The 'Play As 1996 Cast' button has been clicked.");
    detectGamePlay();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So in your endGame function you have an if statement that is checking to see if the innerHTML is equal to the killer.

```
function endGame() {
        gameStarted = false; // Set game status to false
        episodecount = 0;
        document.getElementById("objecttext").innerHTML = killer;
        console.log("End Game:" + killer);  

        if (document.getElementById("buttonp").clicked === true & document.getElementById("objecttext").innerHTML == killer){
            location.reload();
        }
}
```

You want to make sure that when comparing values, you always use a double equal "==" or triple equal "==="

I added an equal sign in the code snippet above, and that should fix your issue!

Comment: I added the addition you mentioned above, but it still does not reset the loop.

Comment: So it looks like detectGamePlay() is supposed to have your game loop in it correct?

Comment: Yeah so when the game has started it'll play the episodes, but if it's the first episode it'll play the opening scene

Comment: Okay, So it looks like the detectGamePlay function if where your game play loop should exist. I don't see any loop there. I think typically for games its usually a while loop. Something like

while(gameplay) {
   //Game logic
}